# Excel VBA Search date range and delete old entries

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro that will search an entire column of completion dates and delete its corresponding row of data if 90 days have passed since the completion date. Here is what I have so far.

```
Dim RowDate
Dim CurrentDate
Dim Interval
Dim CurrentAddress
Dim ValueCellRange As Range
Dim ValueCell As Range

'Interval set to an appropriate number of days
Interval = 90
CurrentDate = Now()

'Identify starting row for sweep
Set ValueCellRange = Range("G2:G100")

'Set loop to execute until empty cell is reached

For Each ValueCell In ValueCellRange
    If CurrentDate - ValueCell.Value >= Interval Then
        ValueCell.EntireRow.ClearContents
    End If
Next ValueCell

'Clear variable value for next initialization
Set ValueCell = Nothing
```

Comment: What's the issue with this? Isn't it working as expected? BTW change the line CurrentDate = Now() with CurrentDate = Date

Comment: This code works perfectly fine. You don't even need to change Now() to Date, since it will just change the decimal value of the difference between CurrentDate and Cell Value.

Comment: Hello, sorry I submitted this without clarification. This macro does not work well when there are blank cells within the range G2:G100. I need to add a stipulation that ignores these cells (does not delete the row data) and just moves onto the next to evaluate its cell contents to my argument. Would anyone know the easiest/best way to implement this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to skip blanks add another if statement in your loop

*Edit* added loop through worksheets

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
For Each ws in Worksheets
    Set ValueCellRange = ws.Range("G2:G100")
    For Each ValueCell In ValueCellRange
        If ValueCell.Value <> "" Then
            If CurrentDate - ValueCell.Value >= Interval Then
                ValueCell.EntireRow.ClearContents
            End If
        End If
    Next ValueCell
Next ws
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. However, I do have one more stipulation if I may add. There are two other worksheets in my workbook. They are entirely similar and need to have this macro run on them. In general, this macro needs to run on all three sheets (ranges will be the same). What is the easiest way to go about this? Would creating range objects work? How would I incorporate the range objects to run with the For statement?

Comment: @Scope1414 I've edited the original to do that. All you need to say is `For Each ws In Worksheets....` and it should loop through all worksheets in your workbook.

Comment: annnnd I have one more thing. Lets say a row has its contents cleared that previously resided in the middle of other rows (of which are still not at 90 days since the completion date), how would I move all of the data below up to close the gap left from the deleted row?

Comment: @Scope1414 Hah you're really making me work for the green check mark. Could you post a screenshot of your data?